# To display count using SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below query I have a table name indent I have different indentid count for different locations. But it shows the indentid count for last location. I want to display all location indentID count.

I want to display count like this

```
    15
    20
     1
```

- 15 - for first location
- 20 - second location
- 1 - third Location

Code:

```
 DECLARE @LocationID int

 SELECT @LocationID = LocationID FROM Locations

 SELECT COUNT(IndentID) AS OpenedIndent 
 FROM Indent I 
 WHERE POStatusID IN (1,2) 
   AND I.LocationID = @LocationID
```

Comment: It would help if you gave us a data sample of the table being queried.

Comment: It is problematic to use `SELECT @LocationID = LocationID FROM Locations` without a `where` condition because it is **not** limiting the results to 1 record (you can only assign 1 value to a scalar variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use group by as below

```
SELECT COUNT(IndentID) AS OpenedIndent 
FROM Indent I 
WHERE POStatusID IN (1,2) 
GROUP BY I.LocationID
```

Comment: Yes I don't want to see indentID .I want to display count of all locations .